# flex4 fb send message to other or fb chatroom

Tags: apache-flex

I want send message by fb.
but have some message is not in my friend list

use that code

```
FacebookDesktop.api("http://graph.facebook.com/100003708317770/Link",submitPostHandler,{message:statusInput.text},"POST");
```

but always show error #100

enybody can help
very thx

Comment: Does 'fb' mean Facebook in this post?  Or Flash Builder?  That said; I don't understand what you're trying to do.